# Problema de coneccion entre flutter y mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, flutter

Buenas Estoy con un problma en flutter...

Estoy queriendo acceder a mi base de datos y me salta este error:`[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Connection refused`
ya cambie las direcciones de Ip a mi IP con 10.0.2.2:8000/api y con 127.0.0.1:8000/api.

Ya entre a dar a phpmyadmin a autorizar el ingreso de IP.

con usando Flutter laravel Php.

auth_services

```
 class AuthServices {
  static Future<http.Response> register(
      String name, String email, String password) async {
    Map data = {
      "name": name,
      "email": email,
      "password": password,
    };
    var body = json.encode(data);
    var url = Uri.parse(baseURL + '/auth/register');
    http.Response response = await http.post(
      url,
      headers: headers,
      body: body,
    );
    print(response.body);
    return response;
  }
```

register_screen

```
createAccountPressed() async {
    bool emailValid = RegExp(
        r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+")
        .hasMatch(_email);
    if (emailValid) {
      http.Response response =
      await AuthServices.register(_name, _email, _password);
      Map responseMap = jsonDecode(response.body);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => const HomeScreen(),
            ));
      } else {
        errorSnackBar(context, responseMap.values.first[0]);
      }
    } else {
      errorSnackBar(context, 'email not valid');
    }
  }
```

globals.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const String baseURL = "http://192.168.100.4:8000/api/"; //emulator localhost
const Map<String, String> headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"};

errorSnackBar(BuildContext context, String text) {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    content: Text(text),
    duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
  ));
}
```

Comment: prueba desde el navegador del dispositivo/emulador, para ver si llegas a esa IP, también revisa el androidmanifest para ver si tienes permisos de internet

Comment: el problema es de conectividad no podemos reproducirlo.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa tu android manifest para ver los permisos de internet
android > app > profile > AndrodManifest.xml
y añade esta linea dentro del manifest si no la tienes

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```